# AnglePicker Like Android API19 TimePicker

Tags: java, android, android-timepicker

I want to create an "Angle Picker" like the Android `TimerPicker` in Alarm Clock since API Level 19 KitKat.

I only want to pick an angle between 0 and 360 degrees. Anybody know how to create something like this?

[Android TimePicker in Clock App](http://blogs.computerworld.com/sites/computerworld.com/files/u177/08-android-44-kitkat-clock-selector.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Create your own component:

```
public class AnglePicker extends View { ... }
```

Override the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method. You should draw a circle, a few texts (0º, 90º, º180 and 270º for example)...
You only need a few calls to `canvas.drawCircle()` and `canvas.drawText()`. The most "difficult" part would probably be calculating the text positions. But it's not a big problem, just a little bit of `sin` and `cos`.

Then override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` too, so you can listen to touch events and repaint the component depending on your needs (drawing a line between center and the selected number, highlighting the closest number with an additional `drawCircle`...).
Basically when the user touches your view, calculate the (x,y) position:

```
Point pt = new Point( (int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY() );
```

And get the angle with `double theta = Math.atan2(pt.x-center.x, center.y-pt.y);`. Translate it into degrees or whatever you need, cause `theta` is expressed in radians.

Finally, add a `public double getAngle()` so other components can read the selected angle.
Seems complicated, but it's not. You can search for "android custom view" if you want some code to start with.